# NetLogo: Issues when restricting number of users charging at a certain patch

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a project to model the impact of charging electric cars on the grid and modeling/simulating the driving and charging habits of the car users. I'm getting an issue in my code that unable to resolve yet.

Each location has a limited number of charging ports. For example, WORK has a total of 2 TERMINALS, so only 2 adopters can charge there simultaneously (first-come-first-serve basis). What I want to do is when 2 adopters arrive at WORK, they start charging (if required, i.e. "charging-status" = true). Any additional adopters wait until a port is available there. The adopters who finish charging should vacate the charging port for those in the wait-list, even if they don't leave.

Here's part of my effort (code) that I did:

```
to go
    ...

    charge-car      ; sets the charging-status based on state-of-charge.

    ask adopters
    [
      if charging? and not marked?
      [
        ifelse remaining-ports != 0
        [
          set remaining-ports max list (remaining-ports - 1) 0
          set marked? true
        ]
        [set occupied? true]
      ]

      if marked? and not charging?
      [
        set remaining-ports min list (remaining-ports + 1) terminals
        set marked? false
        set occupied? false
      ]
    ]
    ask adopters with [charging? and marked?]
    [
      set color green
      let battery0 battery
      let charging-speed0 charging-speed
      let battery1 max list 0 ( battery + charging-speed0 )
      set battery min list battery1 battery-capacity
      let charged min list ( battery - battery0 ) charging-speed0
      set charge-demand charge-demand + charged
      set soc battery / battery-capacity
      set range-left battery / discharge-patch
    ]
  tick
end
```

Now, the issue is this: there are multiple location on the map with charging ports. This code gives different results at some locations, even though it is the same algorithm for all locations and agents. For example, if both ports are occupied at certain locations, the "occupied?" will be true for some locations and not all of the ones with all ports engaged. I mean to say, this is showing quite a random response.

Can anyone please help me with this? Is there another way to do what I want to do? Also, please let me know if you need more info to understand my situation.

Thank you!

**Edit:**
This is my code for `to go`

```
to go
...
ask adopters
  [
    if patch-here = current-loc ; choose next target only when reached at a destination (current location)
    [
      choose-target
      set nearest-station min-one-of patches with [location = "charging-station"][distance myself]
    ] ; choose target based on start time and current location

    ; go to target only when NOT at the arbitrary target location
    if target != [0 0]
    [
      let dist-to-targ distance-between current-loc target
      let dist-to-station distance-between current-loc nearest-station
      ifelse dist-to-targ > range-left and dist-to-station < range-left
      [go-to-station nearest-station]
      [go-to-target]
    ]

    if charging = "Charge Car Now"
    [charge-car]
...
 ]
```

where, `charge-car` is

```
to charge-car
  if patch-here = current-loc and charging-point
  [
    ifelse soc < 1
    [
      if charge-power = 1
      [
        set charging-speed 1 / 12
        set charging-status true
      ]
      if charge-power = 2
      [
        set charging-speed 6.6 / 12
        set charging-status true
      ]
    ]
    [
      set charging-status false
      set color blue
    ]
  ]
end
```

and `go-to-target` is

```
to go-to-target
  ifelse patch-here != target
  [
    ; move towards destination and use fuel
    face target
;    set marked? false
    set color blue
    ifelse distance target <= speed
    [set speed1 0.3 * distance target] ; decrease speed as target gets nearer
    [set speed1 speed]
    forward speed1
    set moving? true
    set charging-status false
    if marked?
    [
      set rem-term min list (rem-term + 1) terminals
      type patch-here type "Updated ports" print rem-term
      set marked? false
      set occupied? false
    ]

  ]
  [
    move-to target
    if target != [0 0]
    [set dist-trav distance-between current-loc target]
    set current-loc target
    set moving? false
    set dwell dwell-acq day-ind time-ind position [location] of target places ; calculate dwell time based on arrival time at target
    ifelse dwell < 0
    [
      set dwell 288 - (ticks mod 288) ; spend rest of the time till 24:00 at that location
      set dwell-flag 1
    ]
    [set dwell-flag 0]
    if current-loc = target
    [
      set arrival-time (ticks mod 288)
      set start-time (dwell + arrival-time) mod 288
      set target [0 0]
      set battery battery - (discharge-patch * dist-trav) ; discharge based on distance traveled per tick
      set soc battery / battery-capacity
      set range-left battery / discharge-patch
      if battery < 0
      [set battery 0]
      if soc < 0
      [set soc 0]
    ]
   ]
end
```

where, `rem-term` is same as `remaining-ports` and `charging-status` is same as `charging?`.
I tried adding the same code in the `go-to-target` function, since charging-status changes there first, but that didn't show any change in the results I'm getting.

Comment: I think whats happening is that at some locations, multiple (more than 2) adopters (agents) land at the same time (same tick) and that is causing the issue in the code. I've noticed that locations where agents don't arrive at the same tick, there is no problem. Could anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: is remaining-ports a patch variable? Am I correct in thinking that it is a count of how many slots are available at the patch? So that is the variable that is not updating properly?

Comment: Yes it is variable. You're correct. It doesn't update properly if multiple (more than 2) agents land on a patch on the same tick.

Comment: Can you please show us the code where you check if there is a charging station available? I am expecting to see something like `if remaining-ports >= 1 [...`

Comment: I use "ifelse remaining-ports != 0". Its in the code excerpt in my question. I forgot to change rem-term to remaining-ports. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm also thinking of trying to use two lists: charging-list and wait-list, where charging-list is the list of adopters who are charging at the time, and wait-list is of agents who are waiting at that location for their turn at first-come-first-serve basis. I haven't coded this because I don't know how to save turtles in a list. If you have some idea about this, please point me in that direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code. This sort of thing usually happens because you have multiple `ask turtles` blocks, and you work out the intention in the first block but don't do the behaviour until the second block. In your case, I can see you updating the ports count in the first block, so that doesn't directly apply.

However, I wonder if you're doing something similar with your `if` statements, that turtles are going through different blocks than you expect and the relevant code is missing from the extract that you pulled out. The easiest way to diagnose this type of problem is with `print` statements. See below for one possibility.

```
ask adopters
[ if charging? and not marked?
  [ ifelse remaining-ports > 0
    [ type patch-here print remaining-ports
      set remaining-ports remaining-ports - 1
      set marked? true
      type patch-here type "Updated ports" print remaining-ports
    ]
    [ set occupied? true ]
  ]
  if marked? and not charging?
  [ set remaining-ports min list (remaining-ports + 1) terminals
    set marked? false
    set occupied? false
  ]
]
```

Note that I also changed your code for testing/updating number of remaining ports for clarity.

On your question about lists, there is no problem adding a turtle to a list (eg `set queue lput self queue`) but if you want more detail than that, please ask a separate question. I strongly recommend that you do not make any attempt to introduce queues for your ports until you have the existing code working properly.

Comment: Thank you JenB. Could you kindly elaborate on this: _"you work out the intention in the first block but don't do the behaviour until the second block"_. I do have multiple `ask turtle` blocks but I do not know how can I combine them. Would it help if I post the entire `to go` block here or in another question?

Comment: So I have this specific situation right now: There are 6 agents on a patch right now, and none of them are charging (even though their `charging?` status is `true`, because the patch shows its `occupied` because `remaining-ports = 0`. I think the `remaining-ports` did not update when a previous agent left a port: `if marked? and not charging?` loop did not run for that location and agent. Now the remaining agents are just waiting there and not being charged.

Comment: where in your code does charging? get set to false? At the moment, occupied? can only get set to false when there is an adopter on the patch that is marked but not charging. But you haven't provided the code that sets the charging? flag to true or false. Regardless, my advice stands that you need to add some `print` statements that tell you which bit of code is being run. I would also be using inspect windows to look at a couple of patches.

Comment: JenB, I am following your advice and have used different print statements and used the inspect window to analyze the issue. The program runs perfectly for a while, but then when there is high traffic on one patch, that patch gets messed up, i.e. the `remaining-ports` doesn't show the correct number, `occupied?` status is not true and adopters don't charge but just wait there to be charged, since the `remaining-ports` are stuck to 0.

Comment: I updated my question and added the information regarding charging status

Comment: I figured out the problem!! It was the issue with `fd` statement. It should be after the `rem-term` has been updated. Otherwise that statement is run for the next patch and not the patch where the adopter is charging. Now it is working perfectly! Thank you so much for all your help JenB. I would need help with making those lists though. I will post another question soon.